Unable to select a page for the Pages_Messaging during Facebook app review
I'm currently experiencing an issue while going through the app review process for my application. Specifically, I am unable to select a page when trying to configure the Pages_Messaging feature. I've double-checked my settings and permissions, but the problem persists.
I'm wondering whether this is a known bug or technical issue on Meta's end, or if there might be something in my configuration or account settings that I'm overlooking. Has anyone else encountered this issue, and if so, do you have any insights or recommendations on how to resolve it?

